# Does Google Analytics Store the data offline when the user is not online?

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk, google-analytics-firebase

I am using Google Analytics in my Android App to track some metrics regarding the usage etc.

I was just wondering whether Google analytics will cache the data of a user who uses my app offline and then record it later when his internet gets active?

Basically I wanted to track the number of users who use the app without internet and the number of users who use my app with internet.

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [GA can queue events while offline](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/enable-offline-analytics). I believe those events will be valid for up to 4 hours.

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.1/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.googleAnalytics.initialize();
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer. I am using Google Analytics for my Android App. But just to clarify that does Google analytics automatically cache the analytical data and then send it to the server when the Internet is available? Because in Website mostly the user has to be online but in an Android App the user need not be online.

Comment: No, it does not do it automatically. You'll need to use the above plugin.

Comment: @Sal cangeloso How to use Workbox in android application. Can you please tell in detail.